# Why outputs in PHP and JAVA not equal

Tags: java, php

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlRequest = " <request><merchant_id>46</merchant_id><order_id>33</order_id><amount>3</amount><description>hehe</description></request>";
        String result = encode(xmlRequest);
        String lol = "lol";
        String lolResult = encode(lol);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(lolResult);
    }

    public static String encode(String toEncode) {
        String hashStr = null;

        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(toEncode.getBytes());
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
            hashStr = hash.toString(16);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashStr;
    }
}
```

**Output is:**

> aa4c157df0d6e95c395f2376fca94c7efa35c05d
>
> 403926033d001b5279df37cbbe5287b7c7c267fa

```
<?
$xml='<request><merchant_id>46</merchant_id><order_id>33</order_id><amount>3</amount><description>hehe</description></request>';
$x = sha1($xml);
echo $x;
echo  sha1("lol");
?>
```

**Output is:**

> d3cfa6c8ee0f7f12d28b782ac1eb45b777792e3a
>
> 403926033d001b5279df37cbbe5287b7c7c267fa

So, why string "lol" is equals and string of xml code is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space -  in the beginning of your java version in comparison to php, so it's not the same string

Comment: ok, next issue: 
String ss = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(xmlRequest.getBytes());
give me PHJlcXVlc3Q-PG1lcmNoYW50X2lkPjQ2PC9tZXJjaGFudF9pZD48b3JkZXJfaWQ-MzM8L29yZGVyX2lkPjxhbW91bnQ-MzwvYW1vdW50PjxkZXNjcmlwdGlvbj5oZWhlPC9kZXNjcmlwdGlvbj48L3JlcXVlc3Q-

on PHP instead of - it have +